# split dataset to 1000 row make it sub dataset

Tags: python

I have a large database that contains 820016 rows. I want to read every 1000 rows each time to enter a specific process. How can I split dataframe by for loop or other with new index to splited data?

```
df = pd.DataFrame(df)
i=0
k=1000
y={}
for index , item in enumerate(df,start=1):
    df1=df.iloc[i:k]
    print(df1)
    i=k
    k=k+50
```

or

```
arr = df.to_numpy()
arr = arr.astype(float)
import copy
m=3
i=0
k=50
df= copy.deepcopy(df)
for row in arr:
    df1=df.iloc[i:k]
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! What type of error are you getting with your current approach? Rather than asking "how can I do something", you should try to ask "how do I fix this issue?". You can check out this link for more info on asking questions: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: `+50`: use `+1000` if you want to read in steps of 1000

Comment: In the second code example, the loop does not make any sense. Think about it and understand what it does. That code looks like programming by coincidence.

Answer (score 0):

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"A": range(820016)})

groups = df.groupby(np.arange(len(df)) // 1000)

for group_id, group in groups:
    print(group)
```

This should give you what you are looking for!

Comment: Please don't post only code as answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.

Answer (score 0):

You already suggested using numpy. It has a nice `split` function. But you have to truncate everything that isn't a multiple of your split (1000 in your case).:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
arr = np.ones((820016, 2)) # create some dummy data
df = pd.DataFrame(arr)
modulo = 820016 % 1000 # splitting starts here, yields 16
arr = df.iloc[:-modulo, :].to_numpy() 
splits = np.split(arr, len(arr) / 1000, axis=0)
for x in len(splits):
    splitted_df = pd.DataFrame(splits[x])
```